# Learning bootstrap: column stacking, need new row to stack when resizing

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on learning Angular and Bootstrap for a possible job, so I'm making a simple demo page. I'm having trouble getting a new row to stack after the last div of the previous row when I resize. I have a page that looks like this when it's full-size:

```
Picture|Text|Btn|Btn <- Row 1
[  hidden div      ]
|   12 point col   | <- Row 2
```

Right now, the following happens when I resize down:

```
Picture
|Text12 p col|
Btn
Btn
```

I want the elements to stack like so:

```
Picture
Text
Btn
Btn
|12 pt col|
```

Please see code below. I'm sure there's something basic that I still don't know. I'm not too picky about the column type, I just want the stacking to work.

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="mainFrame" ng-controller="mainController">
      <div class="row" id="row1">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <img src="img/blah.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" id="nameplate">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <p>sit amet dolor</p>
          </br>
          <p>Demo Page</p>
          <p>Frameworks: Angular and Bootstrap</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><div class="btn" id="bluebtn"><p>Push Me!</p></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><div class="btn" id="redbtn"><p>Push Me!</p></div></div>
      </div>

<!-----------------Top of hidden row-------------------------->
<div class="jumbotron container-fluid" ng-show="false"></div>

<!-----------------Top of row 3-------------------------->


<div class="col-sm-12"><p>Test</p><p>Blah</p><p>Blah</p></div>


</div>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
img
{
    height:30vh;
    padding:1vh 1vw;
    position:relative;
    top:8vh;

}


div
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.row div
{
    height:100%;

}

.row div div
{
    height:30px;
}

#nameplate
{
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin: auto;
    text-align:center;

}

#nameplate p
{
    margin:2vh 2vw;

}

#mainFrame
{
    height: 100%;

}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: please make a fiddle so it's easier for us to edit your code

Comment: I found out what a (js)fiddle is, but I can't get it to work. I can't get the libraries I need (Angular, Bootstrap) to work or replicate the problem. I'm sorry I couldn't be much help. I'm very much a beginner to web development. My world is software.

Comment: You can get libraries, look at the left menu

Comment: I think I got the libraries to work, but jsfiddle doesn't act like my browser has been acting (or resize at all). I'm afraid I'm too inexperienced to take on this project. Back to software for me. Thanks, everyone, for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add different column specification for different screen size. This is responsible for the responsive behavior. You can see the working code snippet below--

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Secure Login: Protected Page</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          </head>
          <body>

<div class="container-fluid" id="mainFrame" ng-controller="mainController">
      <div class="row" id="row1">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 ">
          <img src="img/blah.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" id="nameplate">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <p>sit amet dolor</p>
    
          <p>Demo Page</p>
          <p>Frameworks: Angular and Bootstrap</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><div class="btn" id="bluebtn"><p>Push Me!</p></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><div class="btn" id="redbtn"><p>Push Me!</p></div></div>
      </div>

<!---Top of hidden row-->
<div class="jumbotron container-fluid" ng-show="false"></div>

<!---Top of row 3-->


<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"><p>Test</p><p>Blah</p><p>Blah</p></div>


</div>
</body>
  </html>
```